# Como seleccionar datos que tengan una columna cuyo contenido esté contenido en una palabra

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

Quería hacer una consulta en la que me diera todos los resultados los cuales tengan una columna llamada nombre igual a una variable, e aquí está el problema, que su columna grupo este contenida en 'chocolatepanazucarnocilla'. Es decir, que este contenida, vale chocolate, pan, y cualquier combinación que encaje. He investigado, y no he encontrado mucha información. Solo que si le pones % delante y detrás funciona, pero a mi no. ¿Hay algún otro método? Muchas gracias.

```
<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE nombre = '".$autor."' AND grupo = '%chocolatepanazucarnocilla%' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
$publicacion = $mostrar['publicacion'];}?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si chocolate, pan, azucar etc... son palabras independientes la sentencia correcta sería la siguiente

```
SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE nombre = '".$autor."' AND grupo = '%chocolate%' OR grupo = '%PAN%' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1
```

y así sucesivamente O puedes utilizar la palabra reservada en MYSQL `REGEXP`

```
SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE nombre REGEXP 'chocolate|pan' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1
```

recuerda separar las palabras con el caracter `|` esto buscará la palabra en la columna desde cualquier posición es decir puede estar la palabra chocolate al inicio o final pues esta lo encontrará.

puedes leer mas al respecto de REGEXP en la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. He utilizado el método REGEXP, ya que el otro, al no ser siempre las mismas palabras y haber una gran cantidad de palabras no me servía. Gracias.